# gzip-js does not work, Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript

I would like try gzip-js. and I make a html file to use function of gzip-js

I went https://www.npmjs.com/package/gzip-js, made "npm i gzip-js", as they suggested, the I got some files anf folders,then I wrote an html file(which is in the folder "\node_modules\gzip-js\lib")

```
<html>
<script src="gzip.js">
 var gzip = require('gzip-js');
 var out = gzip.zip('Hello world');
 console.log(out);
</script>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

I hope it will work as the website show, but I was told   "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at gzip.js:4 at gzip.js:280"
in the console of my browser.

Comment: You need `require`, the gzip library itself is not involved in this problem. Although you might not even need `require` - you are already linking the script.

Comment: is the path to gzip.js correct?

Comment: hi,@VLAZ thank you. but the file "gzip.js", is downloaded automatically after "npm i", not written by me. so in this case I need to modify it? And I went to check the file gzip.js, the wrong part is just var crc32 = require('crc32')

Comment: hi  @Natsathorn, thank you. yes I think so. the html file is in the same folder of gzip.js.. I saw the wrong part is just var crc32 = require('crc32'), and crc32 is not in the same folder as gzip.js. But the location of these files are not decided by me, it was downloaeded after i did "npm i"

Comment: @canwang this is nothing to do with the gzip library - you are using `require` which is an entirely different library and you're not importing it, nor configuring it anywhere. Moreover, it's not needed, since you *have* the file - `require` will load the file for you whereas  `<script src="gzip.js">` already does it.

Comment: @VLAZ: thank you . i think error "r: require is not defined", it means error in gzip.js, not in my html file. and may I ask is it possible to solve the problem and make it run? . also, i tried commeted var gzip = require('gzip-js');, and still the same error. thank you